# Python function class, and __init__

Tags: python, function, class

I currently have this code

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, make, model, yearOfManufacture, mileage):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.yearOfManufacture = yearOfManufacture
        self.mileage = mileage

    def get_make(self):
        return self.make

    def get_model(self):
        return self.model

    def get_year(self):
        return self.yearOfManufacture

    def get_mileage(self):
        return self.mileage

    def set_make(self, make):
        self.make = make

    def set_model(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def set_year(self, yearManufacure):
        self.yearOfManufacture = yearManufacure

    def setmileage(self, mileage):
        self.mileage = mileage

    def __str__(self):
        return append.(self.__dict__)

vehicle1 = Vehicle("Honda", "Civic", 2014, 50000);
print(vehicle1)
print("The mileage of this vehicle is:", vehicle1.get_mileage())
vehicle1.set_year(2012)
print("The year of manufacture of this vehicle is:", vehicle1.get_year())
```

which gives the output as

```
{'make': 'Honda', 'model': 'Civic', 'yearOfManufacture': 2014, 'mileage': 50000}
The mileage of this vehicle is: 50000
The year of manufacture of this vehicle is: 2012
```

How can I make it show as

```
Make: Honda; Model: Civic; Year of Manufacture: 2014; Mileage: 50000
The mileage of this vehicle is: 50000
The year of manufacture of this vehicle is: 2012
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't work, but did you try writing a `__str__` method to do what you describe?

Comment: @Kafia Kindly check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the `__str__` magic method to as follows:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f"Make: {self.make}; Model: {self.model}; Year of manufacture: {self.yearOfManufacture}; Mileage: {self.mileage}"
```

**Output:**

```
Make: Honda; Model: Civic; Year of manufacture: 2014; Mileage: 50000
The mileage of this vehicle is: 50000
The year of manufacture of this vehicle is: 2012
```